# Largest and second largest number in array C++ problem

Tags: c++

I want to find the largest and second-largest number in the array. I can find the largest but second largest becomes same as largest and don't know why

```
int main()
{
    int number[10];
    cout<<"enter 10 numbers\n";
    for (int i =0;i<=9;++i){
        cin>>number[i];
    }

    int larger2=number[0],larger=number[0];
    for(int a=0;a<=9;++a){
       if(number[a]>larger) {
           larger=number[a];
       }
    }

    for(int b=0;b<=9;++b){
       if(  number[b]>larger2 && larger>larger2 ){
           larger2=number[b];
       }
    }


    cout<<"larger       "<<larger<<endl;
    cout<<"larger 2     "<<larger2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One possible problem is that if number[0] is the largest number then larger and larger2 will both be equal to it and that's wrong for larger2.  You should make them be equal to INT_MIN  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Comment: Can you just write an example where you hard-code the array, that still exhibits the problem? I'm not going to spend any time typing groups of ten random numbers to see if I can reproduce your problem...

Comment: it doesn't work when I input 1 to 10
Also, I initialized INT_MIN, compiler gave error ```error: ‘INT_MIN’ was not declared in this scope``` (I use an online compiler ) @JerryJeremiah

Comment: when i input 1 to 10 it gaves both larger and larger2 as 10 @Useless

Comment: @GamarMustafa Because of this: `larger>larger2`. Just try to debug your app step-by-step. And you'll see when `larger2` becomes wrong.

Comment: [`INT_MIN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) comes from the header `<climits>`. Or you can use [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) from `<limits>`. That website is useful for looking up which header you need to include ...

Comment: The problem is `number[b]>larger2 && larger>larger2`  Let's say that number[b] is the largest number in the array - it will definitely be bigger than larger2 and larger is already the largest number so larger will be bigger than larger2 as well.  That makes the if statement true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify your second evaluating loop to this:

As you have not correctly assigned larger2 in at least one iteration, so you should not use it for comparisons. (ie Do not do this `larger>larger2`)

```
for(int b=0;b<=9;++b){
   if(  number[b]>larger2 && larger>number[b]){
       larger2=number[b];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this (this works only if there are at least 2 element in the array, otherwise `number[1]` will produce a segmentation fault):

```cpp
int main()
{
    int number[10];
    cout<<"enter 10 numbers\n";
    for (int i =0;i<=9;++i){
        cin>>number[i];
    }

    int larger2=min(number[0],number[1]) ,larger=max(number[1],number[0]);
    for(int a=0;a<=9;++a){
       if(number[a]>larger2) {
           if(number[a]>larger1){
               larger2=larger;
               larger = number[a];
           }
           else larger2=number[a];
       }
    }


    cout<<"larger       "<<larger<<endl;
    cout<<"larger 2     "<<larger2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The explanation is this:

1. take the biggest from the first 2 number and assign to `larger` and the smallest to `larger2`
2. loop through the array and if the current number is bigger than `larger2` we need to store that value in `larger` if it's the bigger, and so the second bigger will be the olfd value of `larger`, else we need to store it in `larger2`

And that's it.

Also take in account that this algorithm is O(n), because we need to travel the whole array just one time, instead of the original one that i O(n*2) because you have to travel the whole array two times, so with bigger array size, this will end about in half the time